# 'int' object is not callable error in python list

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
l1=[2,3,4]
sum(l1)
```

Error message: 'int' object is not callable

can anyone please help me with this error..?

I am expecting sum of elements in the list l1

OUTPUT= 9

Comment: What you've posted will run fine assuming you're running it in two lines. I suspect somewhere else in your code you've overridden "sum". Eg `sum = 1`

Comment: Try `print(sum)`. it should say `<built-in function sum>`. Since you've reassigned "sum", you'll get some integer. You can get the original sum function by entering `del sum`. Or, by exiting and restarting your python environment. Make sure you don't assign anything to `sum` in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call sum(l1) function in the next line, because python detect end of line by newline instead of ';' and .etc

```
l1=[2,3,4]
print(sum(l1))
```

also you need to put it in a print() function to print the output.

Comment: While you're correct they need to be on seperate lines, that is not the answer to this specific question. If you run both in the same line you get a `SyntaxError`, not a `TypeError` as the the asker is seeing.

Comment: well i did run the code op shared and reproduced the error.
then solved it by this way and shared it.
i belive the error is shown because sum returns an int value and array expects end of line or a callable object like iteratable functions (for example ' in ' ).

Comment: Semicolons work as a separator, although there is little reason to use them. `l2=[2,3,4];sum(l1)` would compile and run.

Comment: Yes, but when you don't use it python see it as end of line or expects a callable

Comment: OP did have a newline in their code, their question just lacked the proper markdown formatting.

Comment: No, newline added by amin S, he edited OP's question

Comment: @hameddanesh There is no way you got a type error from running `l1=[2,3,4] sum(l1)`. That's simply not how python works. It will always be a syntax error. See here: jdoodle.com/ia/Kjy

Comment: It returns a type error because he trys to call a integer value, actully it's a syntax error in nature.

Comment: @loocid
this will give the same error
4()

Comment: @hameddanesh Of course, but that has nothing to do with the original question. The code was ` l1=[2,3,4] sum(l1)` which cannot give a type error. Your answer fixes a syntax error, not a type error.

Comment: i understand, it's not normal to call the value sum() returns. i believe that's an interpreter level bug, maybe it has something to do with execution priorities

Answer (score 1):

If I run your two lines of code, it works as expected and gives the output 9.

```
> l1=[2,3,4]
> sum(l1)
9
```

This means, that your error is somewhere else in the code, not shown. I suspect, that you named an int variable `sum` somewhere before. This is a tricky bug, that I also had once upon a time. You can name your variables like built-in functions without any error, so a good advice is not to do it at all.
I can recreate the error the following way, just to illustrate:

```
> sum = 5
> l1=[2,3,4]
> sum(l1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [30], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 sum = 5
      2 l1=[2,3,4]
----> 3 sum(l1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Does this solve your problem?